# how can i render a partial view with its linked css files

Tags: node.js, express, partials, express-handlebars

i am using [**express**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and [**hbs**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs) modules in my nodeJS .
i am trying to render my view using **res.render()** method . the problem is , my view loads without css , because the css file link goes through express and doesn't meet any defined URL in **app.get() methods** . so i wanna know , if the view i am trying to load , includes images , css and JS files that are linked to a folder or URL , how do i render my view with its linked files ?

my directory :
index.js
assets / [css , images , js] /
views / partials /

and my index.hbs is in the views ( views/index.hbs ) , which loads without problem but also without linked css files

the ways i tried :
i searched the web and stack overflow for my answer , but i didn't meet any . i have tried to use file system methods to read file and output them , or have tried to look for some methods to do it but i didn't find any answer .

my index.js :

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const hbs = require("hbs");

app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./assets/")));

hbs.registerPartials(path.join(__dirname, "views/partials"), err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.listen(3000, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

the error i receive :
index.hbs is loaded without css , when i click on the link of css in page source i see this -->
Cannot GET /assets/css/main.css
so i would be thankful if any body can tell me how to solve this ?
( i am almost beginner in NodeJS )